# http post with vb 9.0 (2008)

Tags: vb.net, post

I'm coding in vb.net, and I haven't in forever so I'm a little rusty now.
Question is, I want to be able to post data to a website, it can be anything as long as it can call the url (without being in a browser).

a url like

```
http://website.com/login.php?username=USERNAME&password=PASS&rememberme=1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**WebClient** class is the easy way to go. 
Code sample from  http://www.xtremevbtalk.com/showthread.php?t=158765

```
Dim oWeb As New System.Net.WebClient()

oWeb.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")

Dim bytArguments As Byte() = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("q=InTheory")
Dim bytRetData As Byte() = oWeb.UploadData("http://www.google.com/search", "POST", bytArguments )

debug.Write(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytRetData))
```

Comment: It's a partial code sample and won't compile. Modify as needed - e.g. remove debug statement. Also Google other samples http://www.google.ca/search?rlz=1C1GGLS_enCA342CA342&aq=f&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=vb.net+webclient+post, see msdn samples http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx etc ... but WebClient is the key concept here.

Comment: yes, i do that and i get
The remote server returned an error: (405) Method Not Allowed.

Comment: The 405 is a different question. Search for it or post another question about that particular problem on StackOverflow. This isn't a debugging thread and the original question has been answered.